# Postman returning with 401 unothorized when valid token is passed while working with asp.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have following code in startup:

```
     services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                         ValidateIssuer = false,
                         ValidateAudience = false,
                     };
                 });
```

In Authentication  class of auth controller I have following code:

```
 var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Secret").Value);
                     var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescripto
         {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
            new Claim (ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString ()),
            new Claim (ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
          SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

This returns tokenString.
while passing url with token string string from postman returns 401 unauthorized.
The url is:

```
localhost:5000/api/hotel/?Authentication=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJSdXBhayIsIm5iZiI6MTU3NTcxNDU2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTc1ODAwOTYwLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU3MTQ1NjB9.68L1K3cwRDz7CkL2MP6LdESYO0-2rG5wkyURLzvVIrkg_5XcPb1qVoP2pQgEB8DxbTNVCaBwLV_OsIg2GtTJXg
```

Comment: Some problems are there one of them is localhost:5000/api/hotel/? .Here the last slash should remove

Comment: 401Unauthorized not working

Answer (score 2):

Can you just add your token to your request's header from postman, not from queryString.
key: Authentication value: Bearer {your jwt}

Comment: The above url is after ading  key: Authentication value: Bearer {your jwt}